# LINQ: sort child object param

Tags: c#, linq

I have 'Executive' objects that have X number of 'ExecutiveSectionMapping' child objects depending on how many sections that Executive belongs too.

Problem is, when viewing these Executives, the order of the mappings is random. I need to order the child's parameters independently of ordering the executives themselves.
Tried this to no avail:

```
 return _context.Executives
            .OrderBy(x => x.ExecutiveSectionMappings.OrderBy(y=>y.ExecutiveSectionId))
            .ToList();
```

Tried this too:

```
return _context.Executives
            .OrderBy(x => x.ExecutiveSectionMappings.Select((y => y.ExecutiveSectionId)))
            .ToList();
```

and this:

```
     return _context.Executives
            .Include(x=>x.ExecutiveSectionMappings.OrderBy(y=>y.ExecutiveSectionId))
            .ToList();
```

not sure how to proceed... any ideas?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what the desired result is; could you please provide an example? Do you want to access the Executives or the ExecutiveSectionMappings?

Comment: it doesn't really make sense to have them in order when you return them here. What are you doing with it once it's returned? That's where it should be ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this can't be done in your context, but it can be done in memory.

```
List<Executives> executives = _context.Executives.ToList();

executives.ForEach(e => 
    e.ExecutiveSectionMappings = e.ExecutiveSectionMappings.OrderBy(y=>y.ExecutiveSectionId)
   .ToList())
```

Comment: That depends; what is the type of `ExecutiveSectionMappings`?

Comment: Thanks Marc. Just figured this out from other posts elsewhere, but your answer is correct also, so you get the thumbs-up :)